# sscanf : retrieving int from a pattern with unknown occurrence number

Tags: c++, scanf

I read an ascii file with an fstream. A line contains at least two repetitions of the following patern (and at most 128) :

```
 %d %llu %d %d %llu %d %d %llu
```

For each line i need the max of the third %d of each pattern in the line

i can't find a way to do it properly with sscanf.

```
myFstreams->getline (buffer, MAX_BUFF-1);
while( ... ){
    sscanf (buffer," %*d %*llu %*d %d %*llu %*d %*d %*llu",&number);
    if(number>max) max=number;
    //modify buffer ???
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the type of `buffer` ?

Comment: You could use a string stream.

Comment: Do you mean: at least two lines, which follow the pattern?

Comment: the buffer is `char buffer[MAX_buff];`.  For xtofl no the pattern appears a certain number of time in one line

Comment: A file contains pattern: `%d %llu %d %d %llu %d %d %llu`? Or you mean a file contains numbers which can be read by this pattern like: `111 12332423423 2334 3  90234823894 23 444 9823409248` ?

Comment: yes a line can be `111 12332423423 2334 3 90234823894 23 444 9823409248 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something of the sort: (code untested)

```
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
...

std::string line;
while(std::getline(input_stream,line))//delimit by /n
{
    auto line_ss = std::stringstream(line);
    std::string token;
    int number = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int k=0;
    while(std::getline(line_ss,token,' '))//delimit by space
    {
        if(k == 3) // 3rd number
        {
            int i3;
            std::stringstream(token) >> i3; 
            number = std::max(number,i3)
        }

        k = k == 7 ? 0: k+1; //8 numbers in the set
    }
}
```

Comment: I have worked around the stringstream and adapted your answer (code untested ... ^^)

Answer (score 5):

Your approach looks good, kudos for using `%*` to suppress assignment.

You need to add code to check the return value of `sscanf()`, and loop until it fails (i.e. it doesn't return `1`). In the loop, maintain the maximum by comparing each converted value to the largest you've seen so far.

**UPDATE**: I realized I didn't account for the repeating pattern in the same line aspect. D'oh. I think one solution would be to use the `%n` specifier at the end of the pattern. This will write (through and `int *` argument) the number of characters processed, and thus allow you to step forward in the line for the next call to `sscanf()`.

Comment: I think he meant that this pattern repeats in one line, so he is wondering how to modify `buffer` so the next `sscanf` will check the next 8 numbers and not the same ones.

Comment: Use `n` type - it gives you the number of characters read. Then offset buffer by that many bytes.

Comment: @PawelZubrycki, @Agent_L good points, and I must claim I edited in the recommendation to use `%n` before fully reading Agent_L's comment. Thanks, both.

Answer (score 1):

There's one "secret" type used by `scanf` and not by `printf`, that's why it's often forgotten: `%n`

```
while( ... )
{
    //%n gives number of bytes read so far
    int bytesRead =0;
    sscanf (buffer," %*d %*llu %*d %d %*llu %*d %*d %*llu%n",&number, &bytesRead);
    if(number>max)
        max=number;
    buffer +=bytesRead;//be cautious here if using UTF-8 or other MCBS
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked but i prefer the stringstream solution.